# How to setup authorization in android app for google-people api

Tags: android, google-api, google-authentication, google-people-api

I have been referring https://developers.google.com/people/v1/getting-started document to authenticate. 
I have following concerns-

1) I don't find any client secret. Even when I download my client_secret_.json I get only following attributes-
 - client_id, project_id, auth_uri, token_uri, auth_provider_x509_cert_url, redirect_uris.

2) What is authorization code? 
As it is mentioned in document like

```
    // Read the authorization code from the standard input stream.
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("What is the authorization code?");
    String code = in.readLine();
```

Comment: After creating new client id of type Web Application, I got client_id and client_secret both. But, client secret is not available for client id of type Android. Do anyone know how can be setup authorization then for google-people api??